# generate an HTML-file and display it immediately in a WebBrowser-Control in C#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to create a program that is intended to help my kids organize their school-stuff.
I have a method that should read out the Week-class (containing Days which contain subjects) and convert these information to an HTML-based timetable. Unfortunately, you can check in Chrome, that it generates the HTML-code properly, but however, it does not display it.

```
public class TimetableViewer : WebBrowser
{
    Week week;

    public TimetableViewer()
    {
        week = null;
    }
    public TimetableViewer(Week week)
    {
        this.week = week;
        this.Url = new Uri(Application.StartupPath + "\\timetable.html");
        updateView("timetable.html");
        this.Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.Completely);
    }

    public void updateView(string path="timetable.html")
    {
        Subject[,] sub = week.toArray(); // more comfortable to work with
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path);
        writer.WriteLine("<DOCTYPE html>");
        writer.WriteLine("<html>");
        writer.WriteLine("<head>");
        writer.WriteLine("</head>");
        writer.WriteLine("<body>");
        writer.WriteLine("<h2>");
        writer.WriteLine("<table border=\"2\">");
        writer.WriteLine("<tr><td>Montag</td><td>Dienstag</td><td>Mittwoch</td><td>Donnerstag</td><td>Freitag</td></tr>");
        for (int d = 0; d < sub.GetLength(0); d++)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("<tr>");
            for (int s = 0; s < sub.GetLength(1); s++)
            {
                writer.WriteLine("<td>" + sub[d, s].getName() + "</td>");
            }
            writer.WriteLine("</tr>");
        }
        writer.WriteLine("</table>");
        writer.WriteLine("</h2>");
        writer.WriteLine("</body>");
        writer.WriteLine("</html>");
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

"Montag","Dienstag" etc. are the german names for "Monday", "Tuesday" etc. (mainly because I'm german)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the HTML Code to the `webbrowser.DocumentText` Attribute.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<html><body>");
sb.Append("<a href=");
sb.Append("\"");
sb.Append("http://wwww.microsoft.com");
sb.Append("\"");
sb.Append(">Microsoft</a><p>");
sb.Append("Specify a URL:<br>");
sb.Append("<form method='GET'><input type='text' name='address'/>");
sb.Append("<br><input type='submit'>");
sb.Append("</body></html>");
webBrowser1.DocumentText = sb.ToString();
```

That's the example from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229657%28v=vs.80%29.aspx.

I hope it helps. :-)